# Bottom part of view is cut off in simulator and on device (Single view application)

Tags: iphone, ios, view, storyboard

Here is what my storyboard looks like:

[image]

When I run it on the iPhone Retina simulator this happens:

[image]

The same things happens when running it on my iOS device as well.

I followed the "[Your First iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/RM_YourFirstApp_iOS/Articles/00_Introduction.html)" guide on Apple to the letter. I can't seem to figure out why the bottom part is cut off. Is there some new view changes I need to do for iOS 7? I'm using Version 5.0 (5A1412) with iOS 7 GM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running it on the 3.5" Simulator, and looking at your Storyboard it looks like it's designed for the iPhone 5 4" size. There's a button at the bottom of the Storyboard editor that changes the size you're designing for, that'll show you where it's cutting off.[image]

Comment: Brilliant! This was it. Apple should probably update their getting started documents. :)

Comment: First app I did it tripped me up, glad you've sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your button and change the autosizing like below. This will push it up automatically.

[image: stick your button like this, and it will be pushed up]